# How to set default properties of a control programmatically without it bloating the viewstate

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, viewstate

I have a page with a number of controls on.  Some of the control properties/values are loaded from a database.  Others are eg. date combo boxes with numbers 1-31, years 1900-2012 etc. I would like to populate the combo boxes in a for loop, but I've noticed that if I do that even as early as Page_Init, all the values get entered into the viewstate.  I don't want to disable viewstate on those controls since I need it to maintain the value across postbacks when they are hidden.

Effectively, I'm asking how ASP.NET determines what the default values of the control are - it doesn't put values in to the viewstate if I enter them in the markup and I was wondering if anyone knows a way to reproduce that programmatically?

---

test2.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="test2.aspx.vb" Inherits="test2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

test2.aspx.vb

Partial Class test2
    Inherits Page

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If Request("addvals") IsNot Nothing Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
            ddlTest.Items.Add(i)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Just tried during Page_PreInit - same problem.  Also tried ddlTest_Init, which throws an exception

Comment: I've also tried removing the control from the control tree, setting data and re-adding.  Same problem occures

Comment: Why not maintain the values of the hidden controls manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have just found a duplicate of this - it appears that it isn't possible...
[Is it possible to set asp.net control property values in code behind without adding it to viewstate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578713/is-it-possible-to-set-asp-net-control-property-values-in-code-behind-without-add)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) (linked in the duplicate question) You can create the control dynamically and databind it before adding it to the controls collection. This will be good if your databound control does not use excessive item templates (i.e. if it is DropDownList and not a GridView). Another option is to disable the ViewState on the control and make sure you save the state of the hidden controls manually in the ViewState dictionary.

Comment: I was aware of both of those options but I'm dealing with a large number of controls on a page with about 6000 lines of code and I don't really want to start chasing them around all over the place to check all references to each one of them

Answer (score -1):

Values added during the Init phase are not persisted to ViewState (they are added to the ViewState StateBag, but not marked as dirty).

If you want to set default properties while ViewState is being tracked (e.g. during the Load phase or later), then set them before adding the control to the Page's control tree if you don't want them to be persisted to ViewState.  E.g.

```
Label label1 = new Label();
label1.Text = "Some text" // Not persisted to ViewState
Page.Controls.Add(label1);

Label label2 = new Label();
Page.Controls.Add(label2);
label2.Text = "Some text" // Persisted to ViewState
```

Comment: I've just put together a test page to confirm this and if I add values during Page_Init then they still get added to the viewstate (can see it grow in HTML source view).

Comment: I'm dealing with controls that are in markup, not dynamically added, so unless you are suggesting that I remove them from their parent and then re-add them this isn't suitable?

Comment: @wizzardmr42, your test must be flawed - post a simple test and I'll tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: @wizzardmr42 - add them to your question.